# Reactjs Ant-Design Menu - change subMenu appearance

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, right-to-left

I'm developing a Reactjs website and I'm using Ant-Design (antd) library. I have a Menu and I decided to use the vertical mode. Since my website has rtl layout, I need the SubMenu items to be opened in the left side of the Menu box. How can I do that?

I've prepared an image of what I really want to do:
[image]

This is my code:

```
<Layout className="SideMenus">
  <Menu mode="vertical" defaultSelectedKeys={['One']}>
  <Menu.Item key="One">One</Menu.Item>
  <Menu.Item key="Two">Two</Menu.Item>
  <SubMenu key="Three" title="Three">
     <Menu.Item key="Option3">Option3</Menu.Item>
     <Menu.Item key="Option4">Option4</Menu.Item>
  </SubMenu>
</Layout>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Menu level styling use float right and it will automatically pop the sub menu left side

```
<Menu onClick={handleClick} style={{ width: 256 , float : "right"}} mode="vertical">
```

Comment: That's not happening! :/

Comment: That's weird! Your code works correctly here, but I can't see the same change in my code when I add the `style` and change the mode to `vertical-right`. I thought the problem was in `Layout` content, but that wasn't either.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ConfigProvider](https://ant.design/components/config-provider/) over Menu component:

```
<ConfigProvider direction="rtl"><Menu /></ConfigProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no space on the right, the menu will be automatically opened in the left side.

Have you tried `vertical-right` mode? I couldn't really try it, but maybe it is what you are looking for ...

Comment: Since my layout is RTL and the menu is on the rightmost side of the web-page, there's no space on the right. But still it opens in the right side and hides behind the scrollbar!

Comment: I've also tried 'vertical-right', but that's not what I am looking for. It shows the sub-menu items while collapsing the menu box.

Comment: That's weird because for me, it works.
Can you reproduce the issue? Or share your code?

Comment: I've just edited the question and added the code, however that's a usual way to add Menu in antd.